# MySQL - order by field, starting after specific value

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I hope this is even possible.

I got this table:

[image]

I want to parse it by 5 rows each and ordered by score so when I do:

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY score ASC LIMIT 5
```

The result is:
[image]

Now lets say someone adds a new item with `id 11 and score 2` and after that I do:

`SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY score ASC LIMIT 5, 5`

to get the remaining rows then I would receive `id 7` again

How can I prevent that? So getting the remaining items after `id 7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `ORDER BY score, id`, then you should be able to use filtering instead.

```
SELECT * 
FROM test 
WHERE (score = lastScoredDisplayed AND id > lastIdDisplayed) -- Continue with last score
   OR score > lastScoreDisplayed -- continue on to next score
ORDER BY score, id
LIMIT 5;
```

Where `lastScoreDisplayed` and `lastIdDisplayed` are the values from the last row of your previous query.

This kind of technique *can* even be faster than the `LIMIT x, x` technique; `LIMIT x, x` has to sort the entire dataset every time, whereas this technique ends up with a smaller set the further you go.

Comment: On MySQL that technique could indeed be faster for sure assuming correctly indexed offcource as a large offset meaning the first x in `LIMIT x, x` MySQL might need to use a temporary table which might be ram or disk based..   But the needed `OR` also makes it a bit iffy..

Comment: I have a hunch that if there is an index on (score, id), and the table really is just those two fields, that `LIMIT x, x` _might_ be faster... or at least _could_ be since the operation should just be grabbing the next "block" in the already sorted data. Whether MySQL would actually take advantage of that, I am not sure though.

Comment: This wouldn't work when more items would be added instead of one. And id > lastIdDisplayed wouldn't make sense at all when you see the result after ordering, the missing ids 1, 2, 4 and 6 would never be displayed this way

Comment: @EduardUnruh It would work just fine with multiple items added; and `id > lastIdDisplayed` makes sense precisely because of the (modified) ordering. Please provide an example of data that would cause problems.

Comment: How would I get the missing ids with id > 7?

Comment: the `id > 7` only applies to entries with the same score because of the `AND score = lastScoredDisplayed`, I changed the order of the conditions and added comments in the query to make what it is doing a little clearer.

Comment: @EduardUnruh this query makes more sense then yours actually, as you are using a non deterministic ordering.. pagination of any kind always requires a deterministic sorting to be used..  Your is non deterministic because you do `ORDER BY score`  imagine `id|score` -> `1|1`, `2|1` which of those two records is "first" and which is "second" ?  The answer is you can not predict it..

Comment: well ok actually id != lastid AND score > lastscore would do, I should have describe my problem more detailed like when score changes and the id before 37 gets more score but then I guess it's impossible to be accurate without further code before and after the query. For now your answer will do, thanks :D

Comment: `id != lastid AND score > lastscore` doesn't make sense with the information you've given. If there are score changes, it will indeed exclude the last entry, but but if any entry before it has a score increase above that last entry's, they will appear again; additionally, if there are 200 entries with score 5, you will never see more than 5 entries with that score, and possibly only one (if the first with score 5 appears last on a "page").

Comment: If score changes are possible, then you cannot order by score and not expect to see id's reappear unless you keep track of every single id you have already shown.